# Sorting alphanumeric characters which has large numbers (over a million) with commas. but the java is sorting based on the first number, fails assert

Tags: java, sorting, ui-automation

I am reading the values from UI values sorting ascending and descending and validating using sort function but the sorting is failing as you can see the values are sorting based on the initial digit or int value.
How can I fix or sort the whole number along with the alphabetical words i.e.; unknown, error and so on.

```
public void sortFunction(List valuesFromUI){ 
    List<String> sortValues = new LinkedList<String>(); 
    sortValues.addAll(valuesFromUI)); 

    **Ascending values from UI:**
    [Unknown, Unknown, 13,125, 65,029, 280,552, 281,012, 987,072, 988,775, 1,250,203, 2,363,356, 4,042,563]

    **Descending values from UI: **
    [4,042,563, 2,363,356, 1,250,203, 988,775, 987,072, 281,012, 280,552, 65,029, 13,125, Unknown, Unknown]

    //Ascending
    Collections.sort(sortValues ); 
    System.out.println("[1,250,203, 13,125, 2,363,356, 280,552, 281,012, 4,042,563, 65,029, 987,072,         988,775, Unknown, Unknown");

    //Descending
    Collections.sort(sortValues, Collections.reverseOrder()); 
    System.out.println("[Unknown, Unknown, 988,775, 987,072, 65,029, 4,042,563, 281,012, 280,552, 2,363,356,     13,125, 1,250,203]");
 }
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please show a [complete but minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). By "complete", I mean there should be enough code for us to be able to copy-and-paste into our IDEs,  compile it, and run it. You may also take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), review [How to Ask a Good Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) with other pages they link to.

Comment: In the interest of saving time, my guess is you are getting the results sorted according to their values as `String`s, but want them sorted as integers. If that's the case, you might be interested in using the [sort method with `Comparator`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Collections.html#sort(java.util.List,java.util.Comparator)

Answer (score 2):

You will need to write your own `Comparator` which parses strings containing numbers with thousands separators as integers, and recognises your special values `Error` and `Unknown`.

This answer makes some simplifying assumptions:

1. All your numbers are positive, so we can use `-1` and `-2` as sentinel values for `Unknown` and `Error`.
2. All your numbers are integers.
3. We explicitly use the `US` `Locale`, so only `,` as a thousands separator will work.

```
import java.text.NumberFormat;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Locale;

public class ComparatorExample {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] data = {"Unknown", "Error", "13,125", "65,029", "280,552", "281,012", "987,072", "988,775", "1,250,203", "2,363,356", "4,042,563"};
        List<String> sortValues = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(data));
        sortValues.sort(new MyComparator());
        System.out.println(sortValues);
    }
}

class MyComparator implements Comparator<String> {
    NumberFormat format = NumberFormat.getNumberInstance(Locale.US);

    @Override
    public int compare(String o1, String o2) {
        try {
            int n1 = value(o1);
            int n2 = value(o2);
            return n1 - n2;
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

    private int value(String v) throws ParseException {
        if (v.equals("Unknown")) {
            return -1;
        } else if (v.equals("Error")) {
            return -2;
        } else {
            return format.parse(v).intValue();
        }
    }
}
```

This is a relatively expensive `Comparator`, as it parses strings into numbers every time it does the comparison.

A more efficient approach would be to do a single pass through the `List`, counting the occurrences of `Unknown` and `Error`, and putting any integers into a `List<Integer>` which is then sorted.

The difference would only be noticeable with large numbers of strings -- perhaps tens of thousands.

Answer (score 1):

Left pad numbers with zeros when comparing them as strings:

```
sortValues.sort(Comparator.comparing(s -> !s.matches("\\d[\\d,]*") ? " " + s : String.format("%09d", Integer.parseInt(s.replace(",", "")))));
```

This compares each element converted to a string as follows:

- if the element is not all digits and commas, prepend with a space (so it orders low - before numbers), eg `"Unknown"` -> `" Unknown"`)
- otherwise, remove commas and left-pad with zeros to a fixed width of 9 digits (pick a number of digits at least as big as your largest expected input), eg `"65,029"` -> `"000065029"`

---

To reverse the sort order, add `.reversed()` to the `comparing()` call (plus due to generic weirdness you must explicitly type the call to `comparing()`):

```
sortValues.sort(Comparator.<String, String>comparing(s -> s.matches("\\d[\\d,]*") ? " " + s : String.format("%09d", Integer.parseInt(s.replace(",", "")))).reversed());
```

Comment: Thank you so much, it worked for the above scenario but when i used the same method to sort a tab where there are only words i meant alphabetical values eg: (Unknown, Error, No/values, Null) to sort, i am getting the number format exception as it is integer, I am now using exception to handle that number format exception.. but is there a way to avoid the try and catch block method.

Comment: @Mountain I've changed test for a non-number to "not all numbers or commas". See edited answer.

Comment: When i used the above edited test, its actually considering the first number i.e: unsorted 112,245,65, 99, 100 to 100,112,245,65,99. Thanks again.

Comment: @Mountain my code works; it does not "consider first number" etc. See [live demo](https://ideone.com/CVsHot).

Comment: Thank you, you're right. The issue is when I use the reverse order the error so what i did is. I used the previous condition in the s.matches (s -> s.matches("[a-zA-Z]+") and its sorting right and when there is an empty string i am getting an errror like: 
 Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "". So i did (".*") ? instead but then sorting is failing so i am now trying to include both the conditions to handle empty string as well as the alpha numeric numbers.

Comment: @Mountain My code for the reverse sort works: `sortValues.sort(Comparator.<String, String>comparing(s -> !s.matches("\\d[\\d,]*") ? " " + s : String.format("%09d", Integer.parseInt(s.replace(",", "")))).reversed());`. Change it at your own risk.

Comment: I also have time and date format in one of the scenario for example: "2023-10-04 18:05:12","2023-10-04 18:06:22","2023-10-04 18:04:12","Unknown","2023-10-04 17:05:45","2023-10-04 18:04:45","2023-10-04 18:04:47","2023-10-04 18:03:15", "Error". In this case when reversed the Text values are coming in the beginning and time format following text. Where as the expected should be time format first then the text as it is for: "8,850,675","25,447,948","8,850,675","5,304,942","429,896","1,941,539", "105,886","Error","Unknown".  I tried various methods but failed to achieve it. Thank you for your time.

Comment: Why should timestamps be expected to be ordered before text?? Your question as stated has been answered. If you have a new question (which it seems you have), please create a new question.

Comment: No No, what I meant is I am trying to use the same logic to sort the Time Stamps. In that case the text is coming before the time stamps. As I was using the same logic which you have provided I have posted here.

Comment: Bohemian, I have posted a new question to sort the time and date stamp format. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77255987/trying-to-reverse-sort-a-list-which-has-the-time-stamps-with-date-and-time-along?noredirect=1#comment136201903_77255987   i couldnt find a way to why the text coming at the end while doing the ascending and vice versa. I really appreciate the help. Thanks