# Trying to reverse sort a list which has timestamps along with the text

Tags: java, regex, list, sorting

I am trying to reverse sort a list which has the date and time stamp values using the reverse sort code:

```
List<String> sortValues = new ArrayList<>(List.of("2023-10-04 18:05:12","2023-10-04 18:06:22","2023-10-04 18:04:12","Unknown","2023-10-04 17:05:45","2023-10-04 18:04:45", "Error"));
```

Code given by @Bohemian, thanks a lot and I appreciate the help.

```
sortValues.sort(Comparator.<String, String>comparing(s -> !s.matches("\\d[\\d,]*") ? " " + s : String.format("%09d", Integer.parseInt(s.replace(",", "")))).reversed());
```

Example input array 1 (i.e. before sort):

```
[Unknown, Unknown, 13, 125, 65, 029, 280, 552, 281, 012, 987, 072, 988, 775, 1, 250, 203, 2, 363, 356, 4, 042, 563]
```

Example input array 2:

```
["2023-10-04 18:05:12","2023-10-04 18:06:22","2023-10-04 18:04:12","Unknown","2023-10-04 17:05:45","2023-10-04 18:04:45","2023-10-04 18:04:47","2023-10-04 18:03:15", "Error"]
```

Using the above code, when there are values like in **example 1** (Numbers) the sort works as expected (numbers first and text values at the end).

But when I do the reverse sort with the date and timestamp values like in **example 2**, the above code is sorting and displaying text values first and date and timestamp following the text. Below is the example.

```
[Unknown, Error, 2023-10-04 18:06:22, 2023-10-04 18:05:12, 2023-10-04 18:04:47, 2023-10-04 18:04:45, 2023-10-04 18:04:12, 2023-10-04 18:03:15, 2023-10-04 17:05:45]
```

Whereas the expected reverse sort should be time/date format first then the text.

Thank you and I appreciate the help.

Comment: “(numbers first and text values at the end)” That is not what your first example contains.

Comment: examples are input list not the reversed sort list.

Comment: Even if you manage to change the sorting to keep dates and non-dates apart, you will still have issues getting Unknown and Error in the same order while reversed.

Comment: The solution here is to create a separate data object with its own compareTo method.  But I’m still not clear on whether non-datetime values come after or before parseable-as-datetime values when sorting.

Comment: I have tested with other types of data like numbers and text,  where numbers comes first in descending/reverse order and text comes after the numbers.

Comment: So Basically the Unknown value should come in the first while doing the ascending order followed by the time stamp and Unknown text should come at the end while doing the descending order. Any help is appreciated. For all other values the text comes first for ascending and time stamp at the end and vice versa. Not sure why the sorting is behaving differently for above time stamp format.

Answer (score 0):

You can utilize the *[DateTimeFormatter](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html)* class to evaluate each entry.

Here is an example.

```java
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ISO_DATE_TIME;
sortValues.sort((a, b) -> {
    try {
        LocalDateTime t = (LocalDateTime) f.parse(a);
        try {
            return t.compareTo((LocalDateTime) f.parse(b));
        } catch (DateTimeParseException e) {
            return 1;
        }
    } catch (DateTimeParseException e) {
        try {
            f.parse(b);
            return -1;
        } catch (DateTimeParseException ee) {
            return a.compareTo(b);
        }
    }
});
```

And, to reverse the order, make another call to *sort*.

```java
sortValues.sort(Comparator.reverseOrder());
```

Output

```
2023-10-04 17:05:45
2023-10-04 18:04:12
2023-10-04 18:04:45
2023-10-04 18:05:12
2023-10-04 18:06:22
Error
Unknown
```

```
Unknown
Error
2023-10-04 18:06:22
2023-10-04 18:05:12
2023-10-04 18:04:45
2023-10-04 18:04:12
2023-10-04 17:05:45
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe your issue is that you arent actually doing anything with your Comparator because the regular expression in the matches method always returns false (and true once its negated). When you realise this your line of code becomes

```
sortValues.sort(Comparator.<String, String>comparing( s->" "+s ));
```

or

```
sortValues.sort(Comparator.naturalOrder());
```

note: this is without the .reverse() method

To fix this you need to add a do two separate sorts (there may be a way to do it with one but this is the best I could do). The first sort is to set the order of all of the times and then after that you want to do a second compare to move all the words to the end. It should look like this:

```
sortValues.sort(Comparator.<String>naturalOrder());
sortValues.sort(Comparator.comparing(s->((String)s).matches("[A-Za-z]*")));
```

then to get the reverse of the time you just have to apply the .reverse() method on the first sort:

```
sortValues.sort(Comparator.<String>naturalOrder().reverse());
sortValues.sort(Comparator.comparing(s->((String)s).matches("[A-Za-z]*")));
```

P.S. The regular expression for match still isn't perfect. It will  return false for any string that contains anything other than letters. If your invalid entries are going to be more complex than that use this instead of the second line:

```
sortValues.sort(Comparator.comparing(s->((String)s).matches(s.matches( "[0-9]{4}[[-][0-9]{2}]{2}.*[[0-9]{2}[:]]{2}[0-9]{2}") && s.length()==19 && s.charAt(10)==' ' )));
```